# Bridge created vm not receiving packets + firewalld

Tags: networking, bridge, firewalld

I’ve create a bridge into cockpit on the main interface of this fedora server host.
I want to be able to access VM like any other host and I wanted to proceed step by step and not create a forwarding system with vibr0 etc.

My VM are not getting any packets. They are at the installation process, so no firewall on their end.
This is not a routing problem on my network equipment either because other ubuntu server etc are working just as fine with bridge etc.
So this is only a problem with bridge0 or firewall-cmd.
So after creating the bridge and put in the VM configuration, did I have to do something more to make it work? like deactivate iptables in sysconfig or something like that?

I’ve tried to add services to the FedoraServer zone since bridge0 was included in that zone like dhcp port 67 but it didn’t get any result either. So I guess that the packets are not forward correctly but shouldn’t be an automatic process when creating a bridge?

Thanks in advance for everything you could provide me with.

Answer (score 0):

Okey found it.
As described [here](https://myredhatcertification.wordpress.com/2015/04/26/firewalld-masquerade-forwarding-transparent-proxy/)

## firewall-cmd --add-masquerade --permanent

## firewall-cmd --reload

Apparently cockpit doesn’t add it to the firewall
Maybe it's just a fedora problem but just in case someone else encounter the same problem in another distribution, I thought it would be a good idea to put it out there.